# symbol is squished inside button

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a xamarin.forms app with some buttons which looks like this:

[image]

The problem is that the arrow to the left is squished for some reason.

Here is xaml code for left and right button:

```xml
<Button x:Name="btn_left" Text="◄" Clicked="btn_left_Clicked" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Padding="-5" FontSize="Large"/> <--! Squished symbol -->
<Button x:Name="btn_right" Text="►" Clicked="btn_right_Clicked" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" Padding="-5" FontSize="Large"/>
```

It's not a big issue, but I would like it to be equal to the other arrows.

Comment: if you swap the left and right arrows what happens?

Comment: I swapped left and right, and the issue followed the symbol. I guess it is a problem with the symbol itself. Its the same problem if I use the symbol in a label

Comment: Maybe you could  consider using image instead of text.

Comment: I guess images would be the right way to do it. For now I have just used ↑↓→← instead.